# Big O and small o notation details

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, asymptotics

I am having trouble understanding both intuitively, and by example, statements involving big $O$ and small $o$ notation.

$1)$ $f(h) = O(h^p)$ then $ f(h) = O(h^q)$ for all $ q ≥ p$.

Why is the previous statement **false**? I thought that intuitively, any function that is bounded above by a power of $h$ will also be bounded above by a higher power of $h$.

$2)$ If $p < q, f(h) = o(h^p)$ and $ g(h) = O(h^q)$, then $ f(h) + g(h) = o(h^p)$.

Why is the previous statement **true**? How can we relation small $o$ to big $O$?

$3)$ If $f(h) = o(h^p)$ and $ g(h) = O(h^q)$, then $f(h)g(h) = o(h^{p+q})$.

Why is the previous statement **true**? I have the same problem with understanding this statement since I don't see how to manipulate expressions with both big $O$ and small $o$.

EDIT: this question refers to $h\rightarrow 0$

Comment: Assuming all $O$ and $o$ are as $h\rightarrow\infty$, I'm pretty sure 1) is true and 2) is false.

Comment: Ah! I think it is because the question is about $h\rightarrow 0$! Even so, I don't see the distinction.

Comment: The thing is that for small $h$ (namely, $h<1$) we have $q>p$ implies $h^q<h^p$ (e.g. $h^2<h$), which is not the case for $h>1$. You can use this for 1) and 2).